# bootstrap 4 col-6 grids not responsive like col-xs-6 grids

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a code snippet here i have used **bootstrap 4 col-6** since col-xs-6 is deprecated .

> My Problem is when the browser window resizes the second col-6 in not
>   going up and down(what i mean is responsiveness).

How to correct this?

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: 3px solid red;">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-6">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="img-responsive" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
 <div class="col-6">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim.</p>
  </div>
 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `col-6` with `col-md-6` this will make the parent `row` span across the page in large screens but the columns will respond vertically in smaller screen sizes

The same is true of `col-sm-6` but using it depends upon which breakpoint you need _

For reference to breakpoint sizes see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: 3px solid red;">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="img-responsive" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim.</p>
  </div>
 
</div>
</div>

 <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, you may want to think about removing the `twitter-bootstrap-3` tag from your post. Although you're making a reference to BS3 deprecation in your post, the tag will call contributors to the question though the problem is not BS3 related

Answer (score 2):

If you add [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) CSS and JS properly `col-6` will work like as `col-xs-6`.

I seen you haven't add Bootstrap@4 CSS and JS file. So no bootstrap component will work without bootstrap CSS and JS file. Here is the template form [your example code](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/ZEYyBXj).

**Starter Template with your HTML** (modified).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Col-6 issue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="border: 3px solid red;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="border: 2px solid yellow;">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="img-fluid d-block" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="border: 2px solid green;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim.</p>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use [Bootstrap Starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template). Also you make mistake for responsive `image` `class`. `img-responsive` `class` deprecated in Bootstrap version 4. Now it's `img-fluid` [Responsive Images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/#responsive-images). If you want to make responsive image then you should remove `width` and `height` `attribute` from `img tag`. Also you have learn CSS3 `flex box`. [Here is the complete guid for flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

> Hope this will help.

Comment: Great explanation with bootstrap 4 starter template and change in img-responsive to img-fluid... each point you noted is informative ...

Comment: this post should itself be a template : )